# Vertical Marquee remove space

Tags: html, marquee, clonenode

I want to include some vertical marquee text to my page `<div>` so that the content will be automatically scrolled.

I found the following code useful;

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" height="250" scrollamount="2" scrolldelay="10" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
content goes here<br>
content goes here<br>
content goes here<br>
content goes here
</marquee>
```

But it adds a white space after the contents. The content re appear only after the whole text scrolled up (something like restart). How can I avoid (or remove) this blank space?

I found it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948707/automatically-vertically-scroll-div-contents-looping) in Stack Overflow and there is something noted `cloneNode()`. I don't know how to implement that.

*Note: Height attribute is not relevant. it has same height of parent `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

1. The `<marquee>` element is non-compliant HTML and should not be used...but that is a whole different argument.
2. By its nature, the element will scroll all the way through the content before looping it again.
3. There are [javascript based solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337330/javascript-marquee-to-replace-marquee-tags) that you can use that will do the same thing but with continuous looping.

Comment: i found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948707/automatically-vertically-scroll-div-contents-looping . How can I add cloneNode() to that?